# Content of plugin is not appearing on menu page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a plugin for wordpress.

```
function dbpresent_admin() {  
include('default.php');  
}
function dbpresent_admin_actions() {  
add_management_page("DB Presentor", "DB Presentor", 1, "db_presentator", "dbpresent_admin");
}  
add_action('admin_menu', 'dbpresent_admin_actions');
```

it is the portion of the code where I am trying to diplay content from default.php file but when I click on the menu item in wordpress it opens the page but does not display any data, kindly help me out

Comment: your codes seems to working fine, have you checked the path is correct of the included file?

Comment: yes I did, actually I am integrating jqSuite as a plugin in wordpress and this snippet is supposed to display the content on db_presentator page but it is not doing so.

Comment: what is containing your `default.php` file, can you show us in http://pastebin.com/

Comment: take a look at this file http://pastebin.com/aA8cADuU

Comment: when i try to run default.php file locally on localhost it gives me no error and displays data correctly. But when I called the same file to display its data on wordpress page it returns a blank page

Comment: have you tried to see the error on console tab?

Comment: yes I have tried everything I could come up with, It show nothing no errors just a blank page

Answer (score 0):

The include path looks wrong to me - change it to require and you should see the error.

Most likely you want to use something like

```
include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'default.php' );
```

Or, require if it is a required file.

```
require( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'default.php' );
```

Comment: Hello, Mark I am having error
**Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/prac/wp-content/plugins/wp-dbpresent/tabs.php**

Comment: Ok, so the fact it's looking for tabs.php confirms that default.php has been included correctly. It's your include statement to tabs.php which is wrong - apply the same theory above and with your grid.php include and it should all work.

Comment: yeah the result i showed above was after applying the same theory on every file i included

Comment: Where does this error occur (I guess in the browser because it's trying to load a local file) - In which case view your error log for server errors. Change the include to require if nothing appears. See [WP_DEBUG](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) for how to debug WordPress and get messages on screen.